# Why do I have a different vowel in "scarf" than I have in "scarves", and how come nobody talks about this?

Tags: pronunciation, phonology, vowels

So in my opinion, *scarves* is pronounced as the dictionary has it: with a Short O or /a/.

But I believe that *scarf* and other "ar" words that are followed by voiceless consonants, are not actually pronounced by most people with a Short O or /a/.  I think they are pronounced with a Short U as in *fun*.  (a short U+R, to be exact).

I think we open our mouths less on a "ar" before a voiceless consonant.  I can't find any data for this, but I feel it.   Am I crazy, or have I been pronouncing *scarf, lark, art, harp*, etc wrong all these years?

I was born in the American Midwest.

Comment: They are the exact same vowel for me. Would you say the fourth pronunciation on this page is like what you hear? https://forvo.com/word/scarf/

Comment: Also, I'd suggest you read about the International Phonetic Alphabet, because I'm not sure if /a/ is what you meant (that's the vowel in "hat"). https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Phonetic_Alphabet#Vowels

Comment: @AzorAhai She’s right: *scarf* has a slightly different vowel than the one *scarves* has in her speech. This is normal in the American Midwest. See *writer/rider*.

Comment: @tchrist Oh, I don't disbelieve her, I just wanted to make sure she was talking about the vowel raising you wrote up in your answer.

Comment: *How come nobody talks about this?*  Shush!!  People are listening!

Comment: @AzorAhai-  Hi actually I hear the 3rd pronunciation most of the time!  The 4th one seemed almost too high and muffled and sloppy.  The first two seemed like Short O to me- same as scarves.  I hear some people say those when they are trying to be very careful about their pronunciation, but I don't believe they consistently use it.   Sorry- I never use this internet phonetic alphabet.  I meant short O.   I call the vowel in hat- short a.  I call the vowel in cot- short O.  I call the vowel in hut - short U.

Answer (score 4):

No, you aren’t crazy; you have a really good ear. And as a native speaker, you can’t have been pronouncing those “wrong” all these years. Your *tart* simply has a very slightly different vowel than your *tars*.

It’s normal to have a “higher” vowel when there’s an unvoiced consonant after it, particularly in North America.  What you’re observing is the same raising that happens in *writer* compared with *rider*: the main /ɑ/ vowel is raised to /ʌ/ as in *cut*.

That means *scarf* comes out as [skʌɹf] but *scarves* comes out as [skɑɹvz]. It may actually be [ɐɹ] rather than [ʌɹ], but that’s a very technical distinction that you probably won’t be familiar with.

Neither of those has an /o/ sound like *wore*/*war* (both either [wɔɹ] or [woɹ]) has, or for that matter like *dwarf* [dwoɹf] does. Oddly, the plural *dwarves* [dwoɹvz] is unchanged in its vowel. That’s curious.

Comment: Do you have a reference for this allophone? I've always heard that with such minimal pairs a voiced consonant lengthens the duration of the vowel (_bid-bit_) but not the vowel height.

Comment: @KarlG [Sure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canadian_raising): “In general, Canadian raising affects vowels before voiceless consonants like /f/, /θ/, /t/, and /s/. Vowels before voiced consonants like /v/, /ð/, /d/, and /z/ are usually not raised.”

Comment: Thank you for assuring me I'm not crazy! I agree with writer and rider.   I would be very interested in your explanation of "it may actually be ___ rather than ____"  That's a technical distinction I'm not familiar with but would love to know.  Sorry- I don't know how to type these symbols here, but I'm not familiar with the upside down ar in the first blank.  I'm very familiar with the distinction between er and short u and short o.  If you could compare your sounds to that or forward me to an article that explains it, I would appreciate it!

Comment: Canadian raising affects /aɪ/ and /aʊ/, neither of which is present here.

Comment: @KarlG It’s the same effect: the same raising of /ɑ/ to [ɐ] or [ʌ], triggered by the same factor of whether it’s followed by an unvoiced consonant. Our arrhotic brethren would consider "ar" in the coda there a "centralizing diphthong", so that's not so different from the "ai" or "au" diphthongs. (Not that I think of "ar" as a diphthong myself.)

Comment: If *dwarves* is an exception, could that have something to do with the fact that the traditional plural is *dwarfs*, while the form *dwarves* was invented by Tolkien?

Comment: I'm from the American Midwest, and I use different vowels in *write* and *ride*, but as far as I can tell I use the same vowel in *knife, life, wife* as in *knives, lives, wives* (the same one as in *write*). Am I unusual?

Comment: @bof Tolkien didn't make it up. The OED has an 1818 citation for it. It's just never been common — well, or hadn't been; it is now.

Comment: @bof I have raising in the *-fe* versions. You may be right about your own speech, or you may not be the best judge of your own allophones. Hard to say.

Answer (score 0):

Basically:  If you have a sensitive ear you likely can detect slight differences in the words you mention, but there are also differences in the sound of a single word from one "native" speaker to the next (even if both speakers have the same regional accent), and often differences, based on adjacent words, wider context, audience, time of day, etc, between two uses of the SAME word by the SAME speaker.

Further, in the examples you're considering, the variations are basically "programmed in" to the speech mechanisms of "native" speakers, so they often can't detect the differences.

And notations such as IPA are insufficiently precise to enable computer pronunciation -- ie, they still rely on human "interpretation".

Net-net:

A) The notation is simply not precise enough to record these variations.

B) There is no great advantage in making the notation more precise since the "noise" (due to the factors noted above) is greater than the potential for increased precision.

Comment: The notation is precise enough to distinguish the vowels in *tight* and *tide*, or *writer* and *rider*.

Comment: @tchrist - Precise enough to *pretend* to make such distinctions.  Other potential distinctions are glossed over.